# libcUrl Bad request. Seem that POST body isn't sent, only header

Tags: c++, post, curl, libcurl

I use this options:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, urlUpload);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, body.length());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body.c_str());
```

I'm trying to upload file to Youtube following [their manual](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_direct_uploading.html#Direct_uploading), header and body of my request is quite the same as in the manual.

I receive Bad request, verbose mode shows the following:

```
* About to connect() to uploads.gdata.youtube.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.XX.XXX... * connected
* Connected to uploads.gdata.youtube.com (74.125.XX.XXX) port 80 (#0)
> POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1

Accept: */*

Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com

Authorization: GoogleLogin    auth=D *** c

GData-Version: 2

X-GData-Key: key=A *** Q

Slug: screen.avi

Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="d31fcjR2"

Content-Length: 910273

Connection: close

Expect: 100-continue



* Done waiting for 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

< Server: Upload Server Built on Aug 29 2011 16:45:26 (1314661526)

< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

< Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2011 12:57:51 GMT

< Pragma: no-cache

< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

< Content-Length: 11

< Connection: close

< 

* Closing connection #0
```

Seems like for some reason body wasn't sent at all, can someone helps me?

UPDATE:

when I disable *Expect:* header I still got the Bad Request.

```
* About to connect() to uploads.gdata.youtube.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.XX.XXX... * connected
* Connected to uploads.gdata.youtube.com (74.125.XX.XXX) port 80 (#0)
> POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1

Accept: */*

Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com

Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=D *** s

GData-Version: 2

X-GData-Key:    key=A *** Q

Slug: screen.avi

Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="d31fcjR2"

Content-Length: 910273

Connection: close



< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

< Server: Upload Server Built on Aug 29 2011 16:45:26 (1314661526)

< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

< Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2011 13:59:38 GMT

< Pragma: no-cache

< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT

< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate

< Content-Length: 11

< Connection: close

< 

* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: The body was not sent because the server didn't answer with the `100: Continue` header. It didn't answer perhaps because it doesn't understand the `Expect` header. Try to disable it (with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`).

Comment: @n.m. I disabled. I also receive the Bad Request, I updated my Question.

Comment: In addition, it looks like you have your newline characters wrong, or something like that. See how only the POST header in the request is preceded by a `>` char in the output, all other lines don't have `>` in the beginning. Normally all headers should be preceded by a `>` char. All the reply headers are preceded by a `<` char like they should. I recommend you sniff the traffic with `tcpdump` or `wireshark` and verify all line endings are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was because of the mistake in the POST body. SO this cUrl option is the right way to form POST request with header.